# Object error on predict() for factor field status

Tags: r, predict

Problem context: model response variable 'status' for prediction. 
Help context: Error in UseMethod("predict"). My thinking is that the field 'status' factor is the issue. Need help in detecting issue in predict.

R code:

```
model.predict <- predict(model.fit, newdata = loans_train_data, type="response")
```

structure data:

```
str(loans_train_data)
'data.frame: 
$amount:num...
$...
$status: factor w/2 levels "Good", "Bad": 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 ...
```

Error in UseMethod("predict")

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Things that work:

```
model.lm <- glm2(formula, data=loans_train_data, family="binomial")
model.fit <- fitted(model.lm)
```

Fails on predict, with Error in UseMethod("predict").

```
model.predict <- predict(model.fit, newdata=loans_train_data, type="response")
```

Comment: S3 method dispatch, which `predict` uses, happens on the first argument, not newdata. What is `class(model.fit)`?

Comment: class(model.fit) is [1] numeric

Comment: I re-arranged the first argument, e.g, c('status', 'rate', 'income'...). The first run example had c('loan_id', 'status', 'rate', 'income'...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use predict on model.lm. Per the documentation for `fitted`, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/fitted, it extracts a vector of values, not the model itself.

Comment: when I execute R: 1)model.fit <- stats::fitted(model.lm)

Comment: when I execute R: 2) model.predict(model.fit, newdata=loans_train_data, type="response"; I still get Error in UseMethod ("predict") no applicable method for 'predict' applied to object of class c('double', 'numeric')

Comment: Error: I used stats::fitter(model.lm) , e.g., fitted(object, …), still 'predict' error...

Comment: use predict on the model.lm object, as I said in my answer.